# How to cast SELECT result to a typed value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

Is there any common practice to use `SELECT` result as a typed value, e.g. for functions arguments?

Could it be something like this?

```
func((SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 1).number::numeric)
```

I thought about `CURSOR` for such a task but I'm not really sure. Thank you for any advice!

I'm using PostgreSQL so if there is any specific solution feel free to share.

Comment: You can  pass a value to a function like this - https://rextester.com/TPMFT47348

Comment: `select func(number::numeric) from numbers where user_id = 1`?

Comment: Thank you, good suggestions. But how about
`func (a,b,c)` and `PERFORM func(select1, select2, select3)`?

Comment: The same way: `select func(a,b,c) from some_table` (assuming the table has the columns a,b and c)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FROM` clause or a common table expression:

```
SELECT func(a.x, b.y)
FROM (SELECT ... LIMIT 1) AS a
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT ... LIMIT 1) AS b;
```

or

```
WITH a AS (SELECT ... LIMIT 1),
     b AS (SELECT ... LIMIT 1)
SELECT func(a.x, b.y)
FROM a CROSS JOIN b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
func( (SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 1)::numeric )
```

The subquery is returning (at most) one value so it is a *scalar* subquery and is equivalent to a scalar reference in the query.

That said, there are many other ways to express this.  For instance:

```
func( (SELECT number::numeric FROM numbers WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 1) )
```

or:

```
(SELECT func(number::numeric) FROM numbers WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 1)
```

or moving to the `from` clause and using a lateral join.  Or calculating the result in a CTE or subquery.